# EndToBegin method error

Tags: java, arrays

I have byte array.
And I want sort in from end to begin.
I wrote this :

```
public static byte[] EndToBegin(byte[] b){
        int i=0;
        while( b.length-i!=0){
            b[b.length-i]=b[i];
            i++;
        }
        return b;
    }
```

byt got error.
Debug Current Instruction Pointer point

```
b[b.length-i]=b[i];
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Are you allowed to tell us the error, or is that Top Secret confidential information?

Comment: `a[a.length]` will always give you an error, for any array `a`.  Indexes only go from 0 to `a.length - 1`.  So when `i` is 0, you will get an error.  Note that fixing this will not make your code work--it has a fundamental flaw in it.  But I'll let you figure this out after you get past the exception.  And next, time, _please do not post a question saying "I got an error", without telling us what the error is_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're trying to reverse the order of the array. If so, then use the [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) library:

```
ArrayUtils.reverse(b);
```

That'll save you a lot of headaches. If you want to code it up yourself:

```
for(int i = 0; i < b.length/2; i++)
{
    byte temp = b[i];
    b[i] = b[b.length - i - 1];
    b[b.length - i - 1] = temp;
}
```

But it's possible you're trying to do something else... if so, you need to explain more...

Answer (score 0):

When `i==0`, `b.length-i` == `b.length` and `b[b.length-i]` ==  `b[b.length]` gives `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, since the valid indices of the array are from `0` to `b.length-1`.